# Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'List' (SOSL query)

Tags: apex, visualforce, list

In "Jeet Singh" visualforce tutorial, there is a part talking about search operation, but I get the error when trying to save the code below, I copied exactly the same. any idea why?

```
public class c6{

    String keyword;
    List<Account> acts;


    //create the get method
    public String getkeyword(){
        return keyword;
    }

    public List<Account> getacts(){
        return acts;
    }

    //create the set method
    public void setkeyword(String s){
        keyword = s;  
    }

    public PageReference search(){
        //using SOSL to perform search operation query
        acts = (List<Account>) [FIND :keyword RETURNING Account(Name, Id, TypeOfCompany__c)]
        return null;   
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because of the missing `semicolon`, you missed `semicolon` in the below line

```
acts = (List<Account>) [FIND :keyword RETURNING Account(Name, Id, TypeOfCompany__c)] ;
```

Also, `SOSL` returns `List<List<sObject>>` so if you try to typecast it to `List<Account>`, then again it will give you compile time error. You can go through [Apex Basics & Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_sosl) trailhead module to learn more on this topic.

So in order to fix that, you will have to assign the result of `SOSL` to `List<List<sObject>>` and then take the first element from that list to get `List<Account>`. This is how your code should look like

```
List<List<sObject>> searchList = [FIND :keyword RETURNING Account(Name, Id, TypeOfCompany__c)] ;
acts = (Account[])searchList[0];
```

Comment: Hi Vijay, thank you for your clear information!!!

Comment: @AdnanZahry Glad to help you !!